# Java List declaration for Integer type generic

Tags: java, list, collections

Can anyone please explain why the below two declaration cases are invalid? Would be very grateful for the help if anyone can volunteer.

Case1: `List<   Integer> ls= new List<  Integer>();`

Case2: `List< List<  Integer>> ll= new List< List<  Integer>>();`

Comment: Is it because List is interface and interface can't be instantiated ? but then below code seems like instantiating with casting  :-                  public interface A
{
}
public class B implements A
{
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    A test = new B();
    //A test = new A(); // wont compile
}

Comment: `B` is a class, `A` is just an interface

Comment: Going to +1 your question just for your profile pic.

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis Thanks a ton man :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List` is an `Interface` not a class.

try using [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 2):

both are invalid becaluse

`List` is an interface and you cannot create its object (simple inheritence isn't it?)
consider this

```
Interface A<> {
}
```

and you are trying to do like

```
A<Something> a=new A<>();
```

is same as

```
List<   Integer> ls= new List<  Integer>();
```

But java got `ArrayList and LinkedList` for that and you must do like

```
List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
```

As `ArrayList` implements `List` interface and extends abstract class `AbstractList`

Answer (score 1):

`List`, more specifically `java.util.List`, is an interface and is a subtype of the `java.util.Collection` interface.

Interfaces cannot be instantiated. Classes (excluding abstract classes) implementing an interface and overriding all its abstract methods are the ones that are instantiated and used.

You can choose from the following `List` implementations of the Java Collections Framework:

- java.util.ArrayList
- java.util.LinkedList
- java.util.Vector
- java.util.Stack

Take a look at [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/list.html) article. It explains how you can use the above classes.

Also, take a look at [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_collections.htm) tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Because `List` in an `interface` and they can never be instantiated.
ArrayList is a implemented class of `List` `interface`.
you can do something like this :

```
ArrayList al =new  ArrayList(); //ArrayList implements List,so this will give you all functionality of List
```